# Passar parametro da linha selecionada para outra view RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sou iniciante em ruby. Tenho uma tabela em uma view, que quando eu clicar na linha/item ele deve pegar o ID da linha selecionada e passar para a outra view que sera acionada, estou a 3 dias pesquisando sobre e não consigo implementar.

A view que deve pegar o ID ou outro parametro para que na outra eu possa tratar o select para trazer informações mais detalhadas >>:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to pedido.id, detalhes_backoffice_pedidos_path(:pedido_id => pedido.id) , :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'create_company', 'height=600, width=600');return false;" %>            
</td>
```

A view("popup") que é chamada quando clicado no id do pedido.
Obs.:Tentei de inúmeras formas, e no momento ela esta assim...>>>>

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div style='display: block;' class="col-xs-6 esquerdo ">
  <label>Num.pedido<%= pedido.id %></label> <br>
  <label>nome</label> <br>
  <label>telefone</label> <br>
</div>
```

Controller>>

```
class Backoffice::PedidosController < BackofficeController
.....
def detalhes
 render :layout => "application"

@pedido = params[:pedido_id]

end
```

Estou totalmente perdido, depois de tanto tentar....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, talvez seja tarde, mas vou tentar ajudar.
Você poderia tentar isso:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to "sua view (Pedido) / #{pedido.id}", detalhes_backoffice_pedidos_path(:pedido_id => @pedido.id), :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'create_company', 'height=600, width=600');return false;"  %>            
</td>
```

ou:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to "sua view (Pedido) / #{pedido.id}", detalhes_backoffice_pedidos_path(pedido_id: @pedido.id), :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'create_company', 'height=600, width=600');return false;"  %>            
</td>
```

ok, deixa eu ver se estamos pensando o mesmo, esse `detalhes_backoffice_pedidos_path`, é para onde você quer mandar o `pedido.id?`

mude aqui também, por favor:

```
def detalhes
       render :layout => "application"
       @pedido = Pedido.find(params[:pedido])
end
```

ps:

Só uma dica, quando for gerar seus códigos, gere em inglês. E de uma pesquisada no site  do Stack em inglês geralmente, a resposta para sua duvida esteja lá.(https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Obrigado! Mas ja tinha conseguido resolver, andei estudando bastante e esse é o básico que deveria saber, e sobre as dicas, obrigado novamente, tenho que melhorar isso.